# GRASS: v.drape, v.split and v.to.db on spearfish sample data

Tags: grass-gis, slope

I am new to GRASS and started training on the spearfish sample data set in GRASS 6.4.3. I selected a bicycle tour and transformed it into a polyline. My next goal is to read out the slope and elevation data from the **elevation.dem** in order to create a 3D polyline. I want to use the **v.drape** function, but although the input polyline had an attribute table containing rows for all the street segments that form part of the bicycle tour, my output 3D-polyline doesn't have an attribute table anymore.

```
v.drape --overwrite input=tour1poly@foo rast=elevation.dem@PERMANENT output=tour1poly3D

Warning: Database connection not defined for layer <0>
```

First of all: Why is that?

Going on, I split the 3D-Polyline (using **v.split** along the vertices) into over 300 segments, so I can calculate the slope of each segment with **v.to.db**. But, of course, I first of all need an attribute table for all the 300+ segments to write their slope into.

Is there a function to help me write the results (coordinates, elevation, length etc. of each line or segment) from v.drape and v.split into an attribute table? So v.to.db can add the slope of each segment to said attribute table?

I know there is v.db.addtable, but how can I access the necessary information to create the proper attribute table with over 300 rows that v.to.db needs?

Answer (score 1):

You run v.db.addtable with the column definitions you need. For example:

```
v.db.addtable tour1poly columns="len double precision, slope double precision, startx double precision, starty double precision, endx double precision, endy double precision, elev double precision"
```

Then

```
v.to.db tour1poly option=slope column=slope
v.to.db tour1poly option=length column=len
v.to.db tour1poly option=start column="startx, starty"
v.to.db tour1poly option=end column="endx, endy"
```

If you want the elevation of the start and end of each line segment then add two additional attrib columns "startx" and "endz". Then use those columns in the option=start and option=end commands above.